# R load libraries only in the local scope

Tags: r, scope, package, r-future

is it possible to have `library()` influence only the local scope?

For example, my script has a `lapply` loop that source() code in other scripts; these scripts load their own libraries, but I would like the namespace to be cleaned after the code in these scripts is executed, so that function in package A called by script 1 do not mask functions in package B called by script 2.

I know there are complete solutions like the `modules` and `import` package, but I would like a simpler base R solution first to scale up only if needed.

Comment: Can't you just use namespaces instead of calling `library`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Bakaburg, @AllanCameron was referring to the fact that you can use function `bar()` from package `foo` by using `foo::bar()` rather than `library(foo); bar()`

Comment: it's a bit more complex than this, I load libraries in an ad-hoc function which also installs them if needed, so the libraries should be defined in these scripts. Then you could say that I don't necessarily need to load them, but I'd like to give these script users (those who will write them) the possibility to write easycode without namespacing everything (it's very annoying to namespace every call in a dplyr pipe).

Comment: Can't you just execute those scripts in a separate session (rather than attempt to clean up after them), for example by using the `callr` package?

Comment: uhm, that could actually be a good idea! Does the new session inherits what is on the calling environment? 
In the meantime I was considering simply to track which packages get added to the search path and remove them once the function has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loadNamespace("pkg")` will load the namespace of the 'pkg' package.  Using `library("pkg")` will also *attach* the 'pkg' package to R's search path.  You can see which namespaces are loaded using `loadedNamespaces()` and which packages are attached using `search()`.  These properties are global to R.  In other word, it is not really possible to make them local.

If you wish to use `library()` inside your function/map-reduce calls without `library()` causing the package to be attached in your current R session, then, as others suggested, you could evaluate your calls in an external R process.

(disclaimer: I'm the author) I propose to use futures ([**future**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future)) for this where you evaluate them external via [**future.callr**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.callr) - a future wrapper for [**callr**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/callr).  *The future framework will take care of exporting objects needed to the external R process.*
Here's an example:

```
library(future)
plan(future.callr::callr, workers = 1)
y <- lapply((1:3)/4, FUN = function(x) value(future({
  library(gtools)
  logit(x)
})))
```

Note how a future is created and its value is immediately retrieved, i.e. `value(future(...))`.  To clarify this fact, you could use:

```
eval_via_future <- function(expr, substitute = TRUE, envir = parent.frame()) {
  if (substitute) expr <- substitute(expr)
  f <- future::future(expr, substitute = FALSE, envir = envir)
  future::value(f)
}
```

```
library(future)
plan(future.callr::callr, workers = 1)
y <- lapply((1:3)/4, FUN = function(x) eval_via_future({
  library(gtools)
  logit(x)
})))
```

If you want to avoid having the user specify the `plan()`, the you do:

```
eval_via_callr <- function(expr, substitute = TRUE, envir = parent.frame()) {
  oplan <- future::plan()
  on.exit(future::plan(oplan))
  future::plan(future.callr::callr, workers = 1)
  if (substitute) expr <- substitute(expr)
  f <- future::future(expr, substitute = FALSE, envir = envir)
  future::value(f)
}
```

so you can do:

```
y <- lapply((1:3)/4, FUN = function(x) eval_via_callr({
  library(gtools)
  logit(x)
}))
```

without loading or attaching **gtools** (it obviously loads other packages needed by **future** and **callr**);

```
> loadedNamespaces()
 [1] "codetools"    "grDevices"    "listenv"      "future"       "ps"          
 [6] "memuse"       "clisymbols"   "prompt"       "digest"       "crayon"      
[11] "rappdirs"     "R6"           "future.callr" "datasets"     "utils"       
[16] "callr"        "graphics"     "base"         "tools"        "parallel"    
[21] "compiler"     "processx"     "stats"        "globals"      "methods"     

> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 [7] "CBC tools"         "toolbox:default"   "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

**UPDATE 2020-07-26**

Here's how to source R scripts in an external R process via a future while at the same time pulling globals from the main R session:

```
future_source <- function(file, envir = parent.frame(), ...) {
  expr <- parse(file = file, keep.source = FALSE)
  expr <- bquote({..(expr)}, splice = TRUE)
  future::future(expr, substitute = FALSE, envir = envir, ...)
}

source_via_callr <- function(file, envir = parent.frame()) {
  oplan <- future::plan()
  on.exit(future::plan(oplan))
  future::plan(future.callr::callr, workers = 1)
  f <- future_source(file, envir = envir)
  future::value(f)
}
```

```
## Two R scripts
cat("log(a)\n", file="a.R")
cat("library(gtools)\nlogit(a)\n", file="b.R")

## A global
a <- 0.42

## Source scripts in external process
y <- lapply(c("a.R", "b.R"), FUN = source_via_callr)
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your replay. Unfortunately I'm not able to use the functions I declared in my script, to use them I'm forced to source() the script again inside the expression. Not a big deal eh

Comment: I tried to pass the whole `as.list(globalenv())` to the `global` argument of future(), but then I get this: `Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : 'con' is not a connection`

Comment: There are certain types of objects that only make sense in the R process they were created.  This includes R _connections_.  This is true regardless of parallelization framework - they can _not_ be exported to another R process. See future vignette 'Non-Exportable Objects' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html) for details and examples.

Comment: I think it's best if you produce a _minimal_ reproducible example - there's too much second-guessing right now of what you're trying to achieve (and also why) - a proper code example will clarify that.

Comment: I found the problem: it was a `source()` call inside the future code which was looking for a `file` variable defined if the function in which was defined. But instead of a "variable not found error" it was producing the "'con' is not a connection" above. This was triggered when I passed `globalenv()` to the future since it then was replacing the parent environment in which `file` was defined.